# Safari crashes after few moments of it launching on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus simulator

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, iphone-6

When I try to launch *`Safari`* on `iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus simulator`, it crashes after few moments of its launching automatically.

I try to close simulator and try once again by launch simulator again but same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out on my own.

Go to `Settings > iCloud`, turn off `Safari` and delete the Safari settings, when asked.

Then turn Safari back on and voilà it works!